# Problem regarding caching. Block offset, Set index and Tag

Tags: computer-architecture, caching

I am currently reviewing for my exam in computer architecture. I've run into a question in the old exam sets that I can't really figure out. The question is regarding caches, more specifically block offset, set index and tag. The question is as follows: 
[image]

The old sets come with solutions. The solution to the problem is as follows:

[image]

Unfortunately, it doesn't state how to get there. I'm at a loss here and would really like to understand this. Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Assuming the system is byte addressable, each block is of size 8 bytes. To address them, we'll need $\log_2(8) = 3$ bits. Thus, the last three bits will correspond to the block offset. You have to do the same for sets also and to find the tag, just subtract index and offset from the total size of the address.

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!